# removing specific content from a feed with ajax js.erb when a user is unfollowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a `follow form` that is `rendered` in numerous areas of my app. There is a `feed view`, where content of `followed` users is shown. When a user is `unfollowed` I need that page to be updated to remove the content of the `unfollowed` user. So one solution would be to put all the `feed content` into a partial and render that partial after a `relationship` is `destroyed` through the `destroy.js.erb` ajax file that is triggered from the `Relationships Controller`.

```
UsersController
def feed
  @user_feed_items = current_user.photo_feed.order('created_at desc').paginate(page: params[:page])
end

class User
def photo_feed
    following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    Photo.approved.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids})", user_id: id)
end

feed.html.erb
  <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
end

_feed.html.erb
<% if @user_feed_items.any? %>
  <% @user_feed_items.each do |feed| %>
    <div class="feed-content">
      <%= render partial: "users/usersforfeed", locals: { feed: feed } %>
    </div>  
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now the `Relationships Controller` looks like this:

```
def destroy
  @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
  current_user.unfollow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
end
```

All that is being passed to the relationships controller through the follow form are the `user.id's` of the `followed` and `follower users`.

So in `destroy.js.erb`:

```
$('.feed-content').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'users/usersforfeed', locals: { feed: ????  ))
```

I cannot render the partial because I have nothing to match up with the feed variable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put a wrapper around each object and then simply removed it with javascript if the user is unfollowed. This is easier than rendering the feed again and nothing is gained in rendering the feed anew.